# SQL Multiple checks between 2 tables and storing them

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using C# ASP.NET on Visual Studio 2005, as well as SQL Server 2005.

Currently I have a project which requires me to check each user for any conflicting roles that they might posses.

I have 2 database. `Users` and `ConflictingRoles`. Below is the structure of the 2 tables:

[image][image]

In `Users`, I have 2 unique users with 4 roles each.

In `ConflictingRoles`, I have 4 rows of conflicing roles.

*James and Jennifer each have 4 roles, and each of them is conflicting with one another.*

I want to form multiple SQL queries, to check each role possessed by each user if they are in conflict with any other role which they posses.

I have a rough idea of how the process will be like, but I am not sure how to portray the idea using multiple SQL queries:

---

1) One row at a time, grep the value *usr.*`UserID` and *usr.*`Role` from **Users** *usr* table.

Store *usr.*`UserID` in to temporary variable `tempUID`, and find matching vales of *usr.*`Role` with *cf.*`Role` in **ConflictingRoles** *cf* table.

2) If *usr.*`Role` matches *cf.*`Role`, grep the value of *cf.*`ConflictingRole` and run through all *usr.*`Role` in **Users** table `WHERE`*usr.*`UserID` matches `tempUID`.

If a match/conflict is found between *cf.*`ConflictingRole` with *usr.*`Role` of user `tempUID`, insert *cf.*`ConflictingRole`, *usr.*`Role` and *user.*`Name` into a separate table, **Results**.

3) Repeat this for all roles that each user posses, and for all users.

---

**Basically is that a user is not allowed to posses both roles which are conflicting each other. If they do, store the name, role and conflictingrole in a table.**

---

It is very confusing for me and I am not sure if there is a simplier way to do it.

If not, I will like to request help from you guys with the SQL queries that I will have to form with my above logical sequence.

```
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DS");
SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
thisConnection.Open();

      //multiple sql commands
      nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "<SQL Query>";
      Console.WriteLine(nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());

      ...
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach:

```
Insert into results(userID, role, conflictingRole)
Select distinct
     U.UserId, U.role, C.conflictionRole
FROM
     users U 
   inner join  --join role with all conflicted roles
     conflictingRoles C
       on U.role = C.role
WHERE
     --chech if user has conflicted role
     exists (
        select * 
        from Users U2
        where  U2.userId = U.userId and
               U2.role = C.conflictionRole
        )
```

Comment: It is more important if you understant it. I have endeavored to make it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u1.UserID, MIN(u1.Role) AS Role, MAX(u2.Role) AS ConflictingRole
FROM Users AS u1
JOIN Users AS u2 ON u1.UserID = u2.UserID AND u1.Role <> u2.Role
JOIN ConflictingRoles AS cr ON cr.Role = u1.Role AND cr.ConflictingRole = u2.Role
Group By u1.UserID, MIN(u1.Role), MAX(u2.Role)
```

Comment: @Thanks Imre L for the help, but I met some errors when I applied it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Note your `Users` table is not fully normalized. Suggestion: users details (`UserId`, `Name`) should be in an 'entity' table and the relationship between user and their roles should be in a separate 'relationship' table.

You haven't posted the constraints of your schema but is could be that in the below code `U1.Role <> U2.Role` can be changed to `U1.Role < U2.Role`. Probably best to check with your business domain expert on this:

```
WITH Users 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('R001', 'James', 'ISP001'), 
                     ('R001', 'James', 'ISP002'), 
                     ('R001', 'James', 'OSF001'), 
                     ('R001', 'James', 'OSF002'), 
                     ('P005', 'Jennifer', 'JEP001'), 
                     ('P005', 'Jennifer', 'JEP002'), 
                     ('P005', 'Jennifer', 'FGA001'), 
                     ('P005', 'Jennifer', 'FGA002'), 
                     ('S055', 'OneDayWhen', 'ISP001'), 
                     ('S055', 'OneDayWhen', 'OSF001'), 
                     ('S055', 'OneDayWhen', 'FGA001')
             ) AS T (UserID, Name, Role)
     ), 
     ConflictingRoles AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('ISP001', 'ISP002'), 
                     ('OSF001', 'OSF002'), 
                     ('JEP001', 'JEP002'), 
                     ('FGA001', 'FGA002') 
             ) AS T (Role, ConflictingRole)
     ), 
     PotentiallyConflictingRoles
     AS
     (
      SELECT U1.UserID, U1.Role, U2.Role AS PotentiallyConflictingRole
        FROM Users U1
             JOIN Users U2
                ON U1.UserID = U2.UserID
                   AND U1.Role <> U2.Role
     )
SELECT *
  FROM PotentiallyConflictingRoles P1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM ConflictingRoles C1
                WHERE C1.Role = P1.Role
                      AND C1.ConflictingRole = P1.PotentiallyConflictingRole
              );
```